# XPages date field value changes from AM to PM

Tags: date, datetime, xpages, xpages-ssjs

I have created a managed bean to handle monitoring field changes on an XPage.  The application requires that all changes to fields be logged.  I have integrated the bean into a custom control on the XPage and it is created/instantiated when the user toggles the control from read only to editable.  There is one Date/Time field set up to display only the date.  The Notes document field is also set to display only the date.  When the bean is instantiated and the SSJS obtains the date via getComponent - it returns the date like this: mm/dd/yy 12:00 AM.  I have another button configured to get all the updated field values when it's clicked.  When I click the second button it flags the date field as having been changed when it hasn't.  The "updated" value is: mm/dd/yy 12:00 PM.  If I trigger the initial and update code in the first button I get AM for both values.  When I trigger both initial and update after the control is switched to edit mode by itself I get PM for both values. So it seems that getComponent is returning different values based upon the partial refresh event for readonly to editable. I tried using the afterRender event, but still get the AM/PM problem.  Has anyone else encountered this problem?  If so, any solutions?  Assuming it's an issue with the mode change, any suggestions on how to capture when the change is complete and then trigger my code?

Answer (score 1):

The default value for a date/time field which only stores a date is 12:00 midday. That's to handle Daylight Savings Time adjustments and I suspect the Java Date() to NotesDateTime conversion is doing the manipulation. (NotesDateTimes that are date only are stored with no timezone, so any conversion of 12:00am across DST boundaries may end up changing the date, whcih you don't want; e.g. adjusting 6 June forward 6 months with a time of 12:00AM would change it to **5** Dec, because it would drop back an hour.

I would recommend setting a default value that includes 12:00PM

Comment: Thanks for replying.  In this case the XPage field is pulling a date value from the underlying Notes document.  Depending on when I query the field for the value I will get be either 1/1/15 12:00 AM or 1/1/15 12:00 PM.  I'm using the onClick event of a button to initialize a managed bean to store the initial value which is the AM version.  When I execute code in another onClick event right after, without changing the field value - I get the PM version.  The events are running in SSJS and there is a partial refresh occuring on the panel containing the field.

Comment: Is the 12:00AM value retrieved from a document created by XPages in an earlier Notes version? I think the 12:00PM version came in in 9.0.1 or 9.0. Another possible reason is if the field just has a date in it prior to accessing from XPages. I haven't tested the various scenarios, but XPages only stores date/times, not just dates, unless also calling .setAnyTime() on the NotesDateTime

Comment: The document may have been created using an earlier version - I'm coming into the project after the fact.  I think it's more of an issue with the panel changing from readonly to editable.  If I trigger the readonly to editable in one event, then execute my code in a separate event (i.e. after the panel refresh has obviously completed) I will get PM for both the initial and "updated" values.  I'm doing all of this via SSJS, so I can't use .setAnyTime unless I create a specific case for dealing with date fields on the Xpage - not exactly the route I want to take.  Thank you for responding.